# Limit contributions

Tags: contributions

We are selling exhibit booths on our website using an online form.  We are almost sold out and don't want someone to pay by credit card only to be rejected.  Is there a way to keep the form active only until the last booth is sold?

I've looked under all these elements of our setup:
Campaign
Manage Contribution Pages
Manage Price Sets
Edit Price Fields

With thanks,
Erin

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use the maximum participants field under an event price set. You can do this on each price item, so for your case you can have the cost to have an outreach booth and set how many spaces are available.

It sounds like you are just using a contribution page and there is no way to limit line items there. At least you will know for next time.